# Would working in a laboratory that produces dietary supplements reflect poorly on me in the future?

Tags: resume, career-development, united-states

I currently work in a respectable laboratory in the United States that I wish to leave for management reasons, among other things. I have a masters degree, but where I live, options are fairly limited and I've had difficulty getting appropriate experience. I recently applied to a quality assurance position in another lab that I thought produced pharmaceutical products and was very excited about the opportunity. Last week, I received a call about an interview and decided to research the company a bit more. I discovered that the laboratory produces dietary supplements and is closely linked to a company that sells things like detox shakes. While I am looking for a position to hold long-term, I imagine I will eventually try and move on to something more interesting to me, very possibly in the medical, pharmaceutical, or health fields.

I understand some of this question is specific to the medical/biology fields, but since I am mostly asking about how it will affect my future career, I felt this was the correct place to ask.

My questions:

1. Will it look bad to potential employers to have worked at laboratory that specializes in alternative medicine?
2. Will the experiences in doing QA for supplements, as opposed to medicine, that have fewer regulations/testing give me the qualifications to apply to a more "scientific" position in the future?

Comment: I'm not really sure how this is answerable. Some people might care, others might not.

Comment: I've put your question on hold since this site cannot offer this kind of specific career advice. Figuring out what looks good on your resume and what doesn't is something you'll have to ask peers or mentors with experience in your field.

Comment: I respect the point that my questions are to specific to a particular field, but I worded my questions specifically to avoid asking for advice on whether to take the job (which is, of course, the one answers I got). I will take my question elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if the "process" in making the supplement is sound and follow recommended best practices, then it should not be a problem with future employers.

i also assume that there are many entry points into the pharmaceutical; doing QA, in itself might have some chemistry involved (testing for food safety...)

In the same vein, I assume there are tons of restaurant chefs that started working at Fast Food joints before pivoting to better restaurants.

Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

- Not happy with current position
- Your area has limited options
- Good experience
- Few people will look down on working for dietary supplements

Check it out.  If you like the interview and get good offer then decide. If the place feels slimy then don't take the offer.